# String index out of range but now sure how

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

So I'm doing some map pathfinding and I keep getting an error

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
```

However I don't understand how it could be out of bounds. The map is 10,10 therefore the x&y array parts go 0-9.

This is my code

```
public boolean[][] passable;

public int[][] passCost;

String[][] twoDMap = {
        { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", ".", ".", ".", "." },// ROW0
        { ".", "X", "X", "X", ".", "X", "X", "X", ".", "." },// ROW1
        { ".", "X", ".", "X", ".", "X", ".", "X", "X", "X" },// ROW2
        { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", ".", "X", "." },// ROW3
        { ".", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", ".", "X" },// ROW4
        { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "X" },// ROW5
        { "X", "X", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "X", ".", "." },// RO6
        { ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "X", "X", ".", ".", "." },// RO7
        { ".", "X", "X", "X", "X", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." },// ROW8
        { ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", ".", ".", "." } };// ROW9

private void createMap() {
    passable = new boolean[twoDMap.length][twoDMap[0].length];
    passCost = new int[passable.length][passable[0].length];
    System.out.println(twoDMap.length);
    System.out.println(twoDMap[0].length);
    for (int x = 0; x < passable.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < passable[x].length; y++) {
            passCost[x][y] = 1;
            System.out.print(twoDMap[x][y]);
            passable[x][y] = twoDMap[y][x].charAt(x) == 'X' ? false
                    : true;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

The error apperas when it gets to the first line in the map, the part where it checks if the selected section contains "X". If it does the problem appears.

Comment: Actually, the exception says it clearly... anyway, look at the answers for additional tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be

```
passable[x][y] = twoDMap[y][x].charAt(0) == 'X' ? false : true;
```

rather than ...`charAt(x)`....

However, there's more to be said about the code....

1. Don't obfuscate it by using `String` where a `char` would do.
2. Don't obfuscate it by expressions like `a == b ? false : true`. Simply `a != b` would do.
3. Using strings makes perfect sense if done like below.

```
String[] twoDMap = {
    { ".....X...." },// ROW0
    { ".XXX.XXX.." },// ROW1
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are testing for `charAt(x)` which in your case if it is ever anything other than `0` will throw this error. Your `String` objects are all 1 character long, so you should do `.charAt(0)`.

Or better yet, just test for `.equalsIgnoreCase("X")'` since all of them are the same character that you want to test for.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

`....charAt(x)` where `x` is up to 10, the length of the `twoDMap`.  Each of your strings only has 1 character (index 0), so any index greater than zero is always out of bounds.